# How to write unit test for one line method(dummy)?

Tags: java, junit

In my class I have following public method:

```
 public boolean sendEmail(String[] recepients, String from, String subject, String templateName,
                             Map<String, Object> params) {
        return sendMail(recepients, from, subject, templateName, null, params, null, null);
    }
```

It is just delegation work to another method (private).

How can I write unit test for this?

Comment: IMO, don't. Just test that `sendMail` accepts null parameters.

Comment: What do you want to test exactly?

Comment: Side note: having one method called `sendEmail` and one method called `sendMail` sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: I have a task to cover by unit tests the class. I am not a author of class

Comment: There is no problem with unit testing one line methods. The problem is that your `sendEmail()` method is just a wrapper that doesn't really do *anything* on its own. It's `sendMail()` that you should be unit testing.

Comment: inner  invocation is private. I shoudn't test private method

Comment: You want to test what exactly? The behavior with different arguments?

Comment: I want to execute task. Task sounds as write unit test for method

Comment: @gstackoverflow you write unit tests because they're a good idea, not because someone told you to write a unit test for every method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether a method just delegates to another (private) method or contains its own code doesn't matter when you write a test.

A good unit test verifies that the unit under test fulfils its contract. The clients of `sendEmail` should neither know, nor care, if the brunt of the work is done in a private or public method.

What is (the `public` version of) `sendEmail` supposed to *do*? That is what your unit test should check. A hint is that "forward its arguments to a private method" is not a correct answer :)

Comment: I agree with but it is not answer to my question.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Your question is "How can I write unit test for this?". This answer does appear to address that question. If you want a more specific answer, you should edit your question so that it is more specific.

Comment: @gstackoverflow but seriously, what does the private method do? I assume it calls some methods on some kind of SMTP service object. If so, you should inject a mock of that service and verify the correct methods have been called in the right way.

Comment: @gstackoverflow That might be, but that's not a problem with your one-line method.

Answer (score 0):

As result I had wrote following code:

```
@Mock
EmailService emailServiceMock;

@Test
public void sendEmailTest() {
    String[] recepients = new String[0];
    String from = "from";
    String subject = "subject";
    String templateName = "templateName";
    Map<String, Object> params = Collections.emptyMap();
    String nullString = null;
    Integer nullInteger = null;
    when(emailServiceMock.sendEmail(recepients, from, subject, templateName, params)).thenCallRealMethod();
    when(emailServiceMock.sendMail(recepients, from, subject, templateName, nullString, params, nullString, nullInteger)).thenReturn(true);
    emailServiceMock.sendEmail(recepients, from, subject, templateName, params);
    Mockito.verify(emailServiceMock).sendMail(eq(recepients), eq(from), eq(subject), eq(templateName), eq(nullString), eq(params), eq(nullString), eq(nullInteger));
}
```

Comment: This isn't a very useful test IMHO. All it does is verify that the one method calls the other. It doesn't tell you whether the method is correct, and itwould break with extremely simple changes to your private method. In other words, it's a "change detector test". See http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2014/05/testing-on-toilet-effective-testing.html and http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2015/01/testing-on-toilet-prefer-testing-public.html

Comment: Google just posted a blog entry about change detector tests: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2015/01/testing-on-toilet-change-detector-tests.html